# align button with input in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to align the `button` with the inputs fields.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
   <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <label for="email">Nome:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <label for="pwd">CNPJ:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
   </div>
   <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>    
   </div>
</form>
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the class `col-lg-6` to button div:

```
<div class="input-group-btn col-lg-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>    
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
   <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <label for="email">Nome:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <label for="pwd">CNPJ:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
   </div>
   <div class="input-group-btn col-lg-6">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>    
   </div>
</form>
```